# exclude duplicate lines before downloading in the list(Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that loads information into the list U_INSERT from web pages. 
The web page contains a table, data from the table I extract using pandas

for example 3 url addresses that contain strings:

```
url 1: 
[[55323600, '1234_MB]
,[55323601, '1582_MB]]
url 2: 
[[55323602, '1245_MB]
,[55323603, '1579_MB]]
url 3: 
[[55323602, '1245_MB]
,[55323603, '1579_MB]]
```

I wrote this but this is not the best way to exclude duplicate lines:

```
RESULTU = []    #contains a list of url-addresses
U_INSERT = []   #data from web pages
for ind,val in enumerate(RESULTU):
    df = pd.read_html(val,header=0)[0]
    df = df.as_matrix().tolist()
    for i in df:
        U_INSERT.append(i)
print (list(set(U_INSERT)))
```

I'm looking for a way to check if the line was previously loaded into the list U_INSERT, then do not download it and go to the next url address.

Comment: Since your values are hashable, and you only want to check prior treating, I'd use a `set` and check using `in`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define `RESULTU` as a set, which will make sure that there are no duplicated entries.

See more on sets [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?#set-types-set-frozenset)